# phpmyadmin csv import with foreign character is not working properly

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, collation

Hi I am stuck with a very basic and messy problem, i have gone through other questions but none of them were solving my problem. I have a `csv` file with some data with foreign characters. when i am inserting it into **MySQL** table one by one by copy pasting it is reflecting properly. But when i am using import function of `phpmyadmin` and importing it using `loadinfile` then it is not reflecting. the data get truncated.The sample data is something like this

> Azienda Unità Sanitaria Locale Di Cesena

It is showing just

> Azienda Unit

Any help in this regard would be very appreciating!!

PS: i have done utf8 selection everywhere

Comment: you can export your table in utf-8 format

Comment: i have already mentioned it is in UTF8 format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open your csv file in editor like notepad++ which gives facility to convert to UTF-8.
If you use notepad++,

- Go to Encoding menu > Convert to UTF-8 (3rd Last option).
- Save your file.

Now try importing your database from csv file.

Answer (score 0):

I miss interpreted question,
Please use mysql administrator ,sqlyog or any other software.

Comment: Using Mysql Administration is is showing Incorrect string value '\xE0 Sani...'

Comment: it means it is not supported string data format for mysql.
Please check the data format of your data.

Comment: it is varhchar(255). you mean to say the name `Azienda Unità Sanitaria Locale Di Cesena` is not fit for varchar